# Why mouse click acts as "backwards"

Tags: mouse

Sometimes when I left-click it makes program go back. In browser it loads previous page. In file explorer it opens previous directory.
I don't know why exactly it happens. Ubuntu settings don't even provide options to set macros.
Absolutely no info in internet for this problem. I could assume that mouse is malfunctioning, but how can mouse execute commands that aren't even existing presented on keyboard. Backspace can't make it.

Comment: Many mice have a button to "go back". Apps like browsers and the Files explorer support that button. I suspect that your mouse sends a "go back" message with some clicks.

Answer (score 3):

What's the model of the mouse device you're using?
A couple of years ago, I had a similar issue with a budget mouse from A4tech, it was happening randomly and it was annoying.
I suspected perhaps it was some "mouse gestures" because the product page on their website mentioned that the mouse supports this kind of stuff, and it was controllable through their driver software which is only available for Windows OS.

I tried many things and finally this worked for me
I listed devices with their ids using `xinput list` and I got this

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ ... <omitted>
⎜   ↳ COMPANY 2.4G Device Mouse                 id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ COMPANY 2.4G Device Keyboard              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ ... <omitted>
    ↳ COMPANY 2.4G Device Keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ COMPANY 2.4G Device                       id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

disabled the the 3 devices that appears when I connect the my mouse USB Bluetooth receiver, in my case it was `xinput disable 9 10 11`
and only kept one `COMPANY 2.4G Device Mouse (id=18)` enabled.
this solved the issue for me.

Maybe try doing something similar, disable additional devices detected

Comment: Thank you for answer. Haven't checked this website since October so couldn't see it. Got rid of that mouse and bought better one. But I hope that now if someone will face this problem in the future they will have the answer. When I was searching for a solution there were no answers in the internet, but now there is